# What's an intuitive explanation of the F-distribution's PDF?

Tags: anova, density-function, f-distribution

I have read on this site an [explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78387/intuition-behind-the-t-distributions-density-function) of the t-distribution, and was interested to read a similar one of the F-distribution. The textbooks I have read generally do not cover this topic.

Comment: Could you please clarify what would constitute an "explanation" of a PDF?  Do you mean a mathematical derivation or perhaps are you looking for insight into its principal qualitative features?

Comment: Insight into its principal qualitative features. The link in the OP is to an answer by Glen_b that to some extent provides such insight. Maybe a better example would have been this related answer also by @Glen_b: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110365/9162. Again, however, it relates to the t-distribution and not the F-distribution. Though the question in that instance was more restrictive, the answer seems to cover all the principal qualitative features of the t-distribution. The question and answer were both quite popular.

Answer (score 0):

The ***t***-distribution and ***F***-distribution are different because of the two degrees of freedom (***dof***) values that go into the latter, as opposed to one ***dof*** value for the former.  The PDF quickly degenerates for high ***F*** values because of the low probability one would see such a large ***F*** value jointly across one of the ***dof*** (the one usually measuring the number of independent variables minus one).  For the ***t*** distribution, one doesn't need to consider this second ***dof*** factor.  Some lecture slides covering this are on: [Statistical Ideas](http://statisticalideas.blogspot.com/p/test.html).