# Why Test Statistic for the Pearson Correlation Coefficient is $\frac {r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test

I am learning hypothesis testing for Pearson Correlation Coefficient. The source did not explain why the test statistic $$\frac {r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ satisfy T distribution with $n-2$ degree of freedom.

Could anyone show me the assumption and proof?

Comment: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/254

Comment: Its square obviously has an $F$ ratio distribution.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151854 for instance.

Comment: @Dason thanks! can't believe I have not find it. Also I am sorry for a question without careful literature search.

Comment: The link provided by Dason does not work anymore

Comment: @Eiffelbear Webarchive copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20130625153233/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/254

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(providing an answer to the question)

When the residuals in a linear regression are normally distributed, the least squares parameter $\hat{\beta}$ is normally distributed. Of course, when the variance of the residuals must be estimated from the sample, the exact distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ under the null hypothesis is $t$ with $n-p$ degrees of freedom ($p$ the dimension of the model, usually two for a slope and intercept).

Per @Dason's link, the $t$ for the Pearson Correlation Coefficient can be shown to be mathematically equivalent to the $t$ test statistic for the least squares regression parameter by:

$$t = \frac{\hat{\beta}}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{MSE}}{\sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2}}}= \frac{r (S_y / S_x)}{\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)(1-r^2)S_y^2}{(n-2)(n-1)S_x^2}}}=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$

Comment: [This Wikipedia Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares#Relation_with_Pearson's_product-moment_correlation) might be helpful to understand the second step in the equation.