# How does one arrive at the t-distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, inference, t-distribution

I have looked ***really hard***, in vain, for a statistics textbook that condescends to explain (to the non-expert) how the $t$-distribution was arrived at.

By this I mean a *well-motivated mathematical derivation* that connects the $t$-distribution to the original problem that Gosset, Fisher, and others were grappling with when they settled on it.

---

Statistics textbooks treat this subject as if it were pure kryptonite.  Just shocking.

---

If someone knows of such a book, please let me know.

**NOTE:** this question is a *reference request*.  I'm not looking for such well-motivated mathematical derivation here.  Rather, I'm looking for a pointer to such a derivation in a book or article.

Comment: e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474733/derivation-of-the-density-function-of-student-t-distribution-from-this-big-integ

Comment: Fisher's geometric arguments are worth a look. e.g. [Here](https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15187/1/43.pdf)'s Fisher, R. A. (1925). "Applications of "Student’s" distribution" (PDF). Metron. 5: 90–104.

Comment: Why not read Gosset's original paper?  It is quite readable: it uses fairly modern language, is not mathematically abstruse or sophisticated, is expansive, and even includes a Monte Carlo simulation!  It is reproduced in Kotz & Johnson, *Breakthroughs in Statistics Volume II: Methodology and Distribution*, Springer-Verlag (1992).  A short prefatory note by E. L. Lehmann puts the paper in context and references follow-up work by Fisher that set these results on a rigorous mathematical footing.

Comment: Mathematical derivations do appear here and are likely to be relevant for many readers.  Here's one thread about them: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151854/a-normal-divided-by-the-sqrt-chi2s-s-gives-you-a-t-distribution-proof/151861#151861

Answer (score 1):

This is developed in many books on mathematical statistics. It is in Bickel & Doksum [https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Basic-Selected-Topics/dp/0132306379](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132306379)  and it must be in Casella & Berger [https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Inference-George-Casella/dp/0534243126/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1503914420&sr=1-1&keywords=casella+berger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)  But maybe you are looking for something more elementary ...

Comment: FWIW: I just got Casella & Berger from the library, and I can't find anything even remotely close to what I'm looking for in it.  In fact, I can't even find "$t$-distribution" (or anything like it) in the index!  In light of this, I don't have much hope for Casella & Berger on this question.  (I'm still trying to get hold of Bickel & Doksum.)

Comment: Second edition of Casella & Berger, page 222.

Comment: @Zen: Thank you!  (I'm still shocked that neither "$t$-distribution" nor "Student" appears in such a book's index.)