# A question about fisher's z transformation detail of his paper published in 1921

Tags: distributions, fisher-transform

Typically, people will use Fisher's z-transformation (arctan) to turn the r into a variable that is approximately normally distributed. When I look though his paper published in 1915(https://www.jstor.org/stable/2331838), i couldn't understand how he reduced dx1dy1dx2dy2 to the simple parts:[image]

Comment: Fisher's Z is the *hyperbolic* arctangent, not the arctangent.  A geometrical explanation of what Fisher is doing here is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85977/919.  Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151969/919 for an account of Fisher's paper in terms of a change to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @whuber Hi, after I read the link you given, I still can't not understand how fisher reduced the 2n dimension equation to the simple 3 dimension part. And though I saw the geometrical explanation of  what Fisher is doing, It was a little abstract for me to imagine in N parts of (xi, yi) space.  I will really appreciate if you can explain how fisher reduced this equation.

Comment: He integrated over the surface of the sphere.