# Trying to understand Fisher's geometric derivation of t distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, t-distribution

I'm trying to understand this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151969/25186 which details Fisher's geometric derivation of the t-distribution.

There are some loose ends in my understand I'm trying to wrap up. For reference, we'll need the figure presented there.

[image: Figure]

In the description of the figure, the answerer says:

> *The figure depicts the upper hemisphere (with $Z \ge 0$) of $S^s$ in $\mathbb{R}^{s+1}$. The crossed axes span the $W$-hyperplane. The black dots are part of a random sample of a $s+1$-variate standard Normal distribution: they are the values projecting to a constant given latitude $\theta$, shown as the yellow band.  The density of these dots is proportional to the $s-1$-dimensional volume of that band, which itself is an $S^{s-1}$ of radius $\theta$.*

So far so good.

> *The cone over that band is drawn to terminate at a height of $\tan \theta$.  Up to a factor of $\sqrt{s}$, the Student t distribution with $s$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of this height as weighted by the measure of the yellow band upon normalizing the area of the unit sphere $S^s$ to unity.*

1. Why is the cone drawn to terminate at $\tan \theta$? What significance does this have? Aren't all points projected on this space at whatever height eligible for projection to the sphere?
2. It seems they use the notation $S^s$ to refer to the surface of an $s+1$ dimensional sphere. Is that correct? If so, I couldn't find other references to this notation anywhere. Can someone point to any links?

Next, about the normalizing constant:

> Incidentally, the normalizing constant must be $1/\sqrt{s}$ (as previously mentioned) times the relative [volumes of the spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area),

3. Why is this?

Comment: "$S^s$" is standard mathematical notation for the $s$-sphere in $\mathbb R^{s+1}.$  I am astonished you cannot find this.  It's in the [Wikipedia article on spheres of higher dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).  As far as terminating the image of the cone goes, how would you propose drawing the full cone which extends infinitely far upwards?  The factor of $1/\sqrt s$ was derived in step 7.

Comment: For the image of the cone, why did you use $\tan \theta$ specifically? What's the significance of that? Why not any other height?

Comment: The factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}$ is fine and probably a consequence of how $t$ was defined, I was having trouble with why its the ratio of volumes of the spheres. Is it because we normalize the smaller unit sphere to have a volume of $1$ unit?

Comment: At this height, the diameter of the cone equals the diameter of the sphere.  That yields a decent figure.   The ratio of volumes indeed arises because of the normalization.  Although only the ratio matters, note that a "unit sphere," by definition, has a *radius* of $1,$ not a volume of $1.$