# Predictive Posterior Distribution of a Bivariate Normal Distribution with Unknown Mean and Variance

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, posterior

I am working on a homework assignment and have been stuck on it for a while and would like to seek for some clarification.

Given a likelihood function $y_i|\theta,\sigma^2 \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ for $i = 1,...,n$, where both $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown.

The conjugate normal-inverse-gamma prior is used

$p(\theta,\sigma^2) = p(\theta|\sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)$, and

$\theta|\sigma^2 \sim N(\mu_0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n_0})$ and $\theta|\sigma^2 \sim Inv-Gamma(\frac{\nu_0}{2},\frac{\nu_0\sigma_0^2}{2})$.

The posterior will be then $p(\theta,\sigma^2|\boldsymbol{y}) = p(\theta|\sigma^2,\boldsymbol{y})p(\sigma^2|\boldsymbol{y})$.

The goal is to show that the posterior predictive distribution of $t = \frac{\tilde{y}-\tilde{\mu}}{\tilde{\sigma}}$ is the t distribution.

However, I am stuck at trying to derive the posterior predictive distribution.

I was given a hint that:

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(\tilde{y}|\theta,\sigma^2)p(\theta,\sigma^2|\boldsymbol{y}) \,d\theta \,d\sigma^2 $

I started off by first expanding $p(\tilde{y}|\theta,\sigma^2)p(\theta,\sigma^2|\boldsymbol{y})$ in the integral, which yielded:

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}-1-1}\cdot exp{({\frac{-\nu_1\sigma_1^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{(\tilde{y}-\theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{n_1(\theta-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}})} \,d\sigma^2\,d\theta $

Then I integrated with respect to $\sigma^2$, and recognising that it has the functional form of the Inverse-Gamma distribution:

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Gamma(\frac{\nu_1+2}{2}) \cdot (\frac{-[\nu_1\sigma_1^2+(\tilde{y}-\theta)^2+n_1(\theta-\mu_1)^2]}{2})^\frac{-\nu_1+2}{2}d\theta$

After this I attempted to complete the square but then this is where I do not know how to proceed

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto \frac{-[\nu_1\sigma_1^2+(\tilde{y}-\theta)^2+n_1(\theta-\mu_1)^2]}{2})^\frac{-\nu_1+2}{2}$

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto \nu_1\sigma_1^2[1+\frac{n_1(\theta-\mu_1)^2+(\tilde{y}-\theta)^2}{\nu_1\sigma_1^2}]^\frac{-\nu_1+2}{2}$

$p(\tilde{y}|\boldsymbol{y}) \propto \nu_1\sigma_1^2[1+\frac{1}{\nu_1}(\frac{(\theta-\frac{\mu_1n_1+\tilde{y}}{n_1+1})^2}{\sigma_1^2})+\frac{n_1(\tilde{y}-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}]^\frac{-\nu_1+2}{2}$\

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think there is an issue with your computation of the posterior distribution $p(\theta, \sigma^2 \mid y)$. It should depend on $y$, but there is no $y$ in your expressions.

Comment: You might find https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52906 to be helpful.